# Filename substitution gives syntax error in script , works in console

Tags: bash, shell

I have several files under /var/log/uwsgi/ named similar to domain.123456789
I'm trying to loop over the files as given below

```
for FILE in /var/log/uwsgi/domain.+([[:digit:]]); do         
    gzip $FILE; 
done
```

this works in console. but when run as a part of a script, i get the following syntax error.

```
script.sh: line 16: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

how can i use substitution in shell scripts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure that the `extglob` shell option is enabled in your script by adding:

```
shopt -s extglob
```

Without this, the shell won't recognise your `+([[:digit:]])` pattern and you will get an error.

You probably already have this set in your bash profile which is why it works in the console.